# How to copy files from Google Drive using gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, gcloud

How can you copy files from your google drive to your instance machine using the "gcloud" command?

I authorised the google drive using -

```
gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access
```

But I can't find any info on how to download files from google drive

Comment: I was also exploring different ways to do this (gdrive, rclone) etc. But I found using Google Colab and SSH to be the easiest option. Google Colab has a nice python package to mount drive. And once mounted, we can run any linux commands to play with those drive files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google CLI `gcloud` does not have features to access files in Google Drive.

The command line option `--enable-gdrive-access` exists to enable permissions so that services such as BigQuery can access Google Drive.

For Windows users, you can direcftly access files stored in Google Drive after installing Google Drive File System: [link](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

For Linux, I am not aware of an official tool. I use Drive CLI: [link](https://pypi.org/project/drive-cli/#description).

Comment: Worth mentioning here that there is also a Go client called gdrive https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive

Comment: @Traveler -  There has not been much development on `gdrive` for about 4 years. However, it looks like development will resume again. Thanks for the link.